# How to find exceptions that were "ignored"?

Tags: scala, exception, checked-exceptions

No need to declare checked exceptions in throws clause or handling them in try/catch block in scala is the feature that I love. But it can be a problem when exception must be handled but was ignored. I'm looking for tools (maybe compiler flag/plugin) to find methods that ignored checked exceptions.

Comment: There was a discussion on the scala debate maillinglist and Martin Odersky said this: http://groups.google.com/group/scala-debate/msg/99369ca6c4959894

Answer (score 0):

One option is catch the exception at a very high level of you application (The top would be the `main`-method).

Another option would be to use an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` (if you are on a JVM):

```
object MyUncaughtExceptionHandler extends Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
  def uncaughtException(thread: Thread, throwable: Throwable) {
    println("Something bad happened!")
  }
}

val t = new Thread(new Runnable {
  override def run() {
    null.toString
  }
});

t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(MyUncaughtExceptionHandler)
t.start()
```

Comment: Seems like the op is looking for a static check and you propose two runtime methods.

Comment: @ziggystar That's right, waiting something bad to happen in production is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no such tools, however one technique I've used successfully is to simply install an at-throw-point break point in your IDE (IntelliJ or Eclipse) for java.lang.Throwable which will pause execution at throw point of *every* java exception (or error) as the program runs and then to keep hitting "play" to see them all (at least on the path of execution you're interested in)

Cheers...